# Mongoose Array of Object inside a model can't parse this as an Array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an array of object inside a model.

```
allItems: {
    type: 'Array'
    default: []
}
```

I want to add,

```
new Item({
    allItems: req.body.allItems
})
```

allItems add as a string as I am seeing req.body.allItems as a string. I guess this is default. How to add this as an array?
I also add this,

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ 
    extended: true 
}));
app.use(cors());
```

Comment: if you want to put that `req.body.allItems` string in the object all you need to do it wrap it with [ ] in you new Item creation

Answer (score 0):

Array is not a mongoose type. Instead, you have to give it an array of items. 
So if you were storing an array of strings, the model would be

```
allItems: {
    type: [String]
    default: []
}
```

Comment: Not working as still I am getting req.body.allItems as a string

Comment: Are you saying your req.body.allitems is of the form "[a,b,c]" instead of ["a","b","c"]?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change your model little bit. In here i used String as the data type

```
const item = req.body.allitems

allItems : [{
    item : {
        type : String
    }
}]

allItems.item = allItems.item.concat({item})
```

Comment: Not working as still I am getting req.body.allItems as a string

Comment: @BrockLesner try to use concat method to insert your data. i'll update my answer

Comment: Same I changed my model, req.body.allItems passes a string so can't concat that in this.

Comment: I got this { item: '[{item: "Potato"}]' } see '[{item: "Potato"}]' a string.